# implement/import map location functionality in php

Tags: php, google-maps

I have this site where you upload a picture and what I need to do is select, on map, where the picture was taken (basically point a spot on the map) and save that in the database or something.

Can anyone help with this, give me some ideas on how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Perform an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) is how..

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then get the lat and lng of where the user clicked on the google map, then use an AJAX request to insert the data into a database such as SQL or mySql

Comment: No, I need to SELECT where the picture was taken, meaning I can choose any point on the map, even lie. I need a concrete map on my screen and the user has to browse it and click on a location.

Comment: Exactly, use the google maps API to get the lat/lng of where the user clicked (using Javascript) then store the information you just got into a database using an AJAX request and some PHP.